# Magento 2 Installation stop at 2%

Tags: magento2, php, installation

Magento 2 Installation step 6 still Stops at 2% !

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Could you check the console log error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this prob by setting for **max_execution_time** to 18000; in php.ini
and save changes , when restart the apache, the installation was reached to 100% .

Answer (score 0):

tried to add "disable-tls": true in composer.json file like this:

```
 "config": {
        "use-include-path": true,
        "disable-tls": true
    },
```

[referernce](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Can-t-install-Magento2-setup-installation-process-does-not-even/m-p/73198#M3083)

it's may because of file/folder permission issue also.

```
cd <your Magento install dir> 

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory 

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder    

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R :<web server group> .

chmod u+x bin/magento
```